# How to hide apps in the launcher?

Tags: android

In some of the launchers, there is an option to hide apps from the launcher. Any idea how this can be done?

I want to hide other apps while my apps is running.

Is this possible? Is there any other method to do this?

Thanks and Regards,
Perumal

Comment: You cannot do it the way that you want to. You'd have to also create a homescreen replacement. If the user is running the stock homescreen (or really any homescreen that is not yours) then you will have no way to remove apps from the list that appears in the drawer. To have that ability would represent a security concern.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can write a app without a activity include

`

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

`

then add a *app widget* to start app

Comment: What I am doing is slightly different, I want to hide all the other apps from the launcher upon starting my apps. Any idea, how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Launcher Intent action, and then start your service at background with regist some broadcast.